# How to refresh access token in concurrent environment?

Tags: elixir

The task is to query one of the Google services via service-to-service authentication mechanism  which assumes obtaining a fresh access token every 60 minutes. So it need be pro-actively refreshed or refreshed upon failed request.

Latest seems to be a defensive technic and not comply with Elixir philosophy. More over there is no way to find out whether request failed due to the access token expiration or because provided credentials (email and secret key) are generally invalid - it'll be the same text and same 401 code.

Maybe anyone can advise on implementation strategy? This will be the library meant to be used by host application and it's assumed that during token refreshment (maybe 90ms?) new requests will be created and in general it would be good for them to wait for new token instead of using soon-to-be-outdated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, in Elixir/Erlang you have about 4 ways to store and use shared data:

1. GenServer or alike - you implement process which holds the key and also queries the API. You send a message to it and it returns the data. You don't bother where the data come from, which keys were used and how. Requests are serialized (*not* done in parallel) which is probably something you don't want.
2. Agent - holds the data (keys) only. You call Agent.get/3 and get keys. Whenever you find out the keys are expired, you call Agent.update/3 to put new keys to the Agent. Or you call update/3 always.
3. ETS tables - the last resort. Do not use it if you don't have a good reason.
4. Any external source - you can read from disk, network etc. Even last-er ;) resort.

For your usecase, the first and second solution are probably almost equivalent. But I would use the second one because of paralelization. You can write something like:

```
defmodule TokenHolder do

  def start_link(user,passwd) do
    Agent.start_link(fn ->
      tok_time = get_token user, passwd
      {user,passwd,tok_time} 
    end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  # refresh the token if older that one hour
  @max_age 60*60*1000000

  def token do
    Agent.get_and_update(__MODULE__, fn state={user,passwd,{token,retrieved}} ->
      now = :os.timestamp
      if(:timer.now_diff(now, retrieved) < @max_age) do
        # return old token and old state
        {token,state}
      else
        # retrieve new token, return it and return changed state
        tok_time = {token,_} = get_token user, passwd
        {token,{user,passwd,tok_time}}
      end
    end)
  end

  defp get_token(user,passwd) do
    token = ... # retrieve token somehow...
    {token,:os.timestamp}
  end

end
```

Then you just do:

```
{:ok,_} = TokenHolder.start_link("user","secret")
token = TokenHolder.token
```

Comment: Miroslav, can you elaborate a little bit about serialization of requests?

Comment: GenServer waits for requests and answers them. One after one, in one process. See http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#call-2

If you want your requests to be answered in parallel, you must use special techniques like give server your PID, spawn new process in server and wait for answer with "receive". But this way you can't change server state by the end of the request.

If you use the code I have given you above, you just get the token in serialized code and then you make a request in your process -> i.e. in parallel.

Comment: You can see example code here: https://gist.github.com/mprymek/0a8f175d6c9201a81c62
Try to put some ":timer.sleep" into "TokenHolder.token" - you will see that operations in KeyHolder are serialized. But calls to MyAPI.users are done in parallel.

P.S. you can run the example with "iex api_test.exs"

Comment: Miroslave, one more question - what does this line actually do `tok_time = {token,_} = get_token user, passwd`?
there is a double assignment and I don't know how to  interpret it.

Comment: The function get_token returns a tuple {token,timestamp}. The first assignment extracts token from the tuple and the second assigns the whole tuple to the tok_time variable. In the strict sense it's not an assignment, it's pattern matching.

P.S. +1 for correct declension of my name, wow! ;)